# Remove object's background & resize object to its content in fabric js

Tags: javascript, image, image-processing, fabricjs

Not sure if I put the right title in the question.

In my project user drops a clothing item to the canvas. Usually the clothing item has some white background and looks like this:

[image]

I apply RemoveColor filter and remove white background. But still the object has the same size as it had before. What I wan to is clip image like this:

[image]

Removing the unnecessary background.

How can I do this and is it possible at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general pipeline is as follows:

1. Load the image and convert to gray scale
2. Threshold image and get a binary image
3. Apply morphological operation, in your case closing should do it. Invert the image to get black background and white foreground.
4. Find connected regions and select largest as you region of interest
5. Crop it out.

**EDIT**
Here is some sample code in Python (using opencv and skimage libraries).

```
img = cv2.imread('test2.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

t, bw_img = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

closing = cv2.morphologyEx(bw_img, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, np.ones((3, 3)))
closing = cv2.bitwise_not(closing)

labels, num = measure.label(closing, background=0, connectivity=2, return_num=True)
max_size, max_blob = 0, None
for l in range(1, num+1):
    blob = np.zeros_like(labels)
    blob[labels == l] = 1
    nz = np.count_nonzero(blob)
    if nz > max_size:
        max_size = nz
        max_blob = blob
assert(max_blob is not None)

x, y = np.nonzero(max_blob)
xmin, xmax = min(x), max(x)
ymin, ymax = min(y), max(y)
max_blob = max_blob[xmin: xmax, ymin:ymax]
# Resized color image
img = img[xmin: xmax, ymin:ymax]
```

**EDIT2** Images corresponding to steps of the code
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for so detailed explanation!